# Default taxes for all countries

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-class

I had configured magento tax for EU countries.
Now my client wants the same taxes applied for all countries in the world.

There is a faster way to set a dafault tax rule for all countries than create a specific rule for each country?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento requires a country when adding a new tax rate. Generally, you'll only need to collect sales tax in countries or regions where you have a business presence. If you want to use a flat rate for any location worldwide, you could set **Tax Calculation Based On** to **Shipping Origin** under System > Configuration > Tax and use a wildcard rate for your origin country. You'll always calculate tax from your shipping origin this way.